# Button fadein jQuery ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I try to give a div fade in effect in ASP.net when the page loads.
But one somehow I do not get it working.

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divbutton').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="divbutton" class="col-md-4 text-center"><a href="#" class="btn-main">Bekijk onze Films</a></div>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your element is currently visible. So you won't notice the effect of fadeIn.

First hide the element and then call the `fadeIn` on the element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divbutton').hide().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

[Here](http:////jsfiddle.net/w79wxnca/) is a working sample.

Or you can add `display:none` css to your HTML markup and simply try your version(without calling hide)

Comment: Thank you it is always the little mistakes that makes the life of a novice programmer difficult XD

Answer (score 0):

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0jz3dxch/)**

Change your html to make it hidden to begin with. Add the style `"display:none"`.

```
<div id="divbutton" class="col-md-4 text-center" style="display:none">
  <a href="#" class="btn-main">Bekijk onze Films</a>
</div>
```

`fadeIn` will work only if the element is hidden first.

Comment: Avoid inline CSS; add a class that hides your element instead.

Comment: @benjarwar - agree with you.. but for demo purposes, this will work. I see that OP is already using classes, so I would suggest to add a class which hides it.

Comment: @Jens - no prob. glad to help.